# how to fix import error in django project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, importerror

> i have a django project, i want to import views from my app called projects

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.project_index, name="project_index"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.project_detail, name="project_detail"),
]
```

> i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/firstwebapp/mysite/projects/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be:

```
from projects.views import project_index, project_detail
```